# Function like var_dump in php

Tags: php, function, return-value, var

I need a function like `var_dump($object)` in php
The problem is that the Var_dump function print every thing on the screen and
I just need the answer in a variable.
I mean sth like `$variable=var_dump($object);` And I dont want to see anything on screen!
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$variable=var_export($object,true);
```

you needs [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Comment: var_export() does not handle circular references as it would be close to impossible to generate parsable PHP code for that. If you want to do something with the full representation of an array or object, use serialize(). And also Variables of type resource couldn't be exported by this function.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you use:

```
$variable = print_r($object, true);
```

Comment: That still prints out put to screen!! and i need sth for objects not arrays

Comment: If you pass true to print_r it will not output to the screen, but store in a variable.

Comment: @Abadis: which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @SalmanA doesn't matter which version, this parametr was added about 4.3 version.

Comment: As i said i need to get it for objects

Answer (score 2):

U can also use the output-control functions

```
ob_start();
var_dump($object);
$description = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes json_encode() can be handy:

```
$variable = json_export($data);
```

Or

```
$variable = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```